# Cant get Element of an HashMap that are new puttet?

Tags: java, constructor, hashmap, element

Hey guys **I have no Idea what happen? I add birthdays but if call them with getHashMap for example I cant get the elements in the class swingmenu.** I just have thoughts about the Problem. I think its because I call new Event in a class and where I output the hashmap in a different class I call new Event too. But I dont know if I am right?

Maybe any Solution would help me. If you have Question then please ask me. For me its important to learn something new. There are some short coded showen because its not relevant. I debug the class swingFormatFunction and find out that the the instance event is null.

This part dont get added into my HashMap.

```
public class swingFormatFunction{
private Event event = new Event();
public void geburtstageFormatieren(String content) {
    String formatContent = content.replace(';', ' ');
    for (String s : formatContent.split("\n")) {
        event.addBirthday(s.substring(0, 5).toString(), new Event(s.substring(12).toString()));
    }

}
}
```

That is my menu where I call a Menuitem and click "ok". This function works fine I get the elements outputted.

```
public class swingMenu{
okBTN.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == okBTN) {
            dialog.dispose();
            JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
            dialog.setModal(true);
            dialog.setTitle("Calendar Special Events");
            int yearNumber = Integer.parseInt((String) yearCombobox.getSelectedItem());
            JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();


            Event event = new Event(yearNumber);
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            for (Map.Entry entry : event.getEventMap().entrySet()) {
                stringBuilder.append(entry.getKey() + " : " + entry.getValue() + "\n");
            }

            textArea.setText(stringBuilder.toString());
            dialog.setContentPane(textArea);


            dialog.pack();
            dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            dialog.setResizable(true);
            textArea.setEditable(false);
            dialog.setVisible(true);


        }
    }
});
```

That is my Event class. This class contains my HashMap where I work with it.

```
    public class Event{
    private HashMap<String, Event> eventMap = new HashMap<>();
    public Event(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Event(int year) {
        addStrongMoveableHolidayInMap(year);
    }

    public Event() {

    }

    private void addMoveableHoliday(int year) {
        /*      Bewegliche Feiertage    */

        /*Rose monday (-48)*/
        int daynumberOfEasterSunday = calenderFunction.easterSunday(year) - 48;
        String gregorDate = calenderFunction.kalenderDatumFuerJD(daynumberOfEasterSunday);

        String day = gregorDate.substring(0, 2);
        String month = gregorDate.substring(3, 5);
        String date = day + "." + month;
        this.eventMap.put(date, new Event("Rosenmontag"));
    }

    private void addStrongHoliday(int year) {
        /*      Feste Feiertage         */
        this.eventMap.put("24.12", new Event("1. Weihnachtstag"));
    }

    void addStrongMoveableHolidayInMap(int year) {
        addStrongHoliday(year);
        addMoveableHoliday(year);
    }

    public void addBirthday(String year, Event event) {
        this.eventMap.put(year, event);
    }

    public HashMap<String, Event> getEventMap() {
        return eventMap;
    }
}
```

I hope you guys can help me.

Best Regards
Manuellsen

Comment: So what exactly are you asking?  If you're asking us to debug your code, then that is not what Stack Overflow is for.  If you're asking something else, please make that clear (and take out those bits of code that do not relate to your specific question).

Comment: We can't answer a question that you didn't ask; sorry.

Comment: manicka understand my question

Comment: I edit a bit but manicka gets me and I think his explentation is better then mine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two event objects are totally independent. 
The first one in `swingFormatFunction` is a instance attribute and the second one in `ActionListener` is a local variable.
The Event's `eventMap` attribute is also an instance attribute, so each `Event` object has its own map. Maybe you want to share one `eventMap` accross all events.

Comment: Ty you understand my question. Is there a easy way to share or how I should make it in your Opinion. Maybe singleton?

Comment: My suggestion is to separate Event (aka named point in time/calendar) and a set of events (the eventMap) into their own classes. And then pass the set of events into swingFormatFunction and ActionListener (by constructor, setter, DI, ...). Implementing it as Singleton is one of the possible solutions.

Comment: And one more note: make the set of events thread safe, if it can accessed from different threads (the ActionListener in AWT thread and the swingFormatFunction somewhere else - that's my guess from your code snippets)